# EF Core: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm new in Entity Framework Core and I have a problem with the next situation.

I have three objects, like this:

```
TableA {

    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public IList<TableA_TableB> TableA_TableBList {get; set;}
}

TableA_TableB {
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public TableA TableA {get; set;}
    public int TableAId {get; set;}

    public TableB TableB {get; set;}
    public int TableBId {get; set;}
}


TableB {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public IList<TableA_TableB> TableA_TableBList {get; set;}
}
```

I'm using the Fluent Api to map the relationship:

```
builder
    .HasOne(a_b => a_b.TableA) 
    .WithMany(a => a.TableA_TableBList) 
    .HasForeignKey(a_b => a_b.TableAId); 

builder
    .HasOne(a_b => a_b.TableB) 
    .WithMany(b => b.TableA_TableBList) 
    .HasForeignKey(a_b => a_b.TableBId);
```

My problem is when I try to insert a new value in TableA with a new value in TableA_TablesB, but there is an existent value TableB. The code that I used is:

```
var entity = (TableA)tableADto; //From controller and convert to TableA using explict operator

entity.TableA_TableBList = new List<TableA_TableBList>();
entity.TableA_TableBList.Add(new TableA_TableB()
{
    TableAId = entity.Id,
    TableBId = 1 // I put a fix value just to test
});

_tableARepository.Add(entity);
_unitOfWork.Commit();
```

When I call `SaveChanges()`, this error is shown:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_TableA_TableB_TableB_TableBId".
>   The conflict occurred in database "tenantteste", table "dbo.TableB", column 'Id".

I have tried to get TableB value and add a navigation property (TableB property). But, instead of creating a relationship, the value was added when I saved.

I have read the documentation and some questions on stackoverflow, and I believe using FK should work, but it didn't work.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the type of `tableADto` and why it needs to be cast to entity? If it is a derived class, the cast doesn't change the actual type. Also what does repository `Add` method look like? Can you reproduce with clean project and pure EF Core model methods, e.g. simple `DbContext`, `Add`, `SaveChanges()`?

Comment: @IvanStoev Has some differences, when i send the object to fronent, like adress: in the front end is a object, but in the back end is on the entity. The method `Add()` is just `context.Set<>().Add` and the `Commit()` just call the `SaveChange()`.

I deleted my old implementation and rewrite step-by-step and worked

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things wrong.  Your linking table should not have a surrogate key, for one.  Here's the Many-to-Many sample from the docs:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.PostId, t.TagId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Post)
            .WithMany(p => p.PostTags)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PostId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
            .WithMany(t => t.PostTags)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId);
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#other-relationship-patterns

Note that the linking entity has a compound key of (PostId,TabId).

Comment: EF Core does not do automatic many-to-many relationships like this. You have to use an explicit join class.

Comment: @Valuator thanks.  I had forgotten that wasn't in EF Core.  Here's the tracking issue: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10508

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use ICollection instead of List in this case?

Comment: I don't see how the type of the link table PK (explicit or composite) is related to the FK conflict exception from the OP. The sample from the docs is just what it says - sample.

Comment: @IvanStoev OP mentioned that when setting a Navigation Property instead of the Foreign Key property, a duplicate linking entity was inserted. At least that's how I interpreted it.